# Отменить стандартное действие кнопок браузера

Tags: jquery

Браузер использует кнопки `стрелка вверх` и `стрелка вниз` для плавной прокрутки страницы. Как можно зарезервировать эти кнопки под себя без получения фокуса элементом?

Т.е. мне удается использовать их только если передать элементу, для которого будут использованы кнопки, фокус:

```
$(function($)
{
    $(document).keyup(function(event)
    {
        // получает фокус при нажатии кнопки F
        if (event.which == 70)
        {
            $( "video" ).focus();
        }
    });
});
```

Тег `video` может потерять фокус и при повторном нажатии кнопки `F` тег  `video` почему-то уже не получает фокус.